# How change the connected Object in Wheel joint 2D Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use Wheel joint 2d so it works fine.But now i want to change the object that is moving.Please see the picture you will be better understand it.I highlighted the area that I want to change through the script.

[!picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIsX7.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIsX7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in the instpector, just click the little circle on the right and select your object in the list.

However, if you want to do this via script, you can use GetComponent() on your gameobject and then change the connectedBody value to another rigibody2D

Hope it helped